# How to get average of uniform arrays in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table in the following format:

| Time | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 18:22:26.544 | [2, 3, 88, 23] |
| 2021-03-15 18:23:26.544 | [7, 12, 45, 11] |

The number of elements in the values array is always fixed (uniform) for e.g. there will always be 4 elements in the values array.

What I am looking for is the average of individual index in the values array.
For eg. `SELECT AVG(values) FROM mytable;`

The output should be:

| avg |
| --- |
| [4.5, 7.5, 66.5, 17] |

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If the number of elements is fixed, then why don't you just use four (or whatever *n*) columns? That would make it easy...

Comment: Actually it's 16 elements, showed 4 for example. I already thought about that but wanted to see if there is another way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to unnest the array, take the averages, and put them back into the array.  Use WITH ORDINALITY to keep track of the index in the array.

```
-- Aggregate the array, ordered by the original index
SELECT array_agg(avg order by i) 
FROM (
    SELECT i, avg(value) 
    -- unnest the values and their indices
    FROM mytable, unnest(values) WITH ORDINALITY as u(value, i) 
    GROUP BY i
) AS sub;
                                    array_agg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {4.5000000000000000,7.5000000000000000,66.5000000000000000,17.0000000000000000}
```